# Bitcoin Block Reward value

Tags: mining-reward

How can someone calculate the current/real-time value of a Bitcoin block?

What is the equation/algorithm used to determine this?

I've found a few resource online, but I'm a little confused

Comment: By value, are you asking about the size of the reward, or the rules about whether it's valid? Or are you talking about the value of Bitcoin?

Comment: Reward for valid block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can someone calculate the current/real-time value of a Bitcoin
>   block?

Steps:

1. run `bitcoin-cli getblockcount` to get current **block_height**
2. current_block_reward = 50 / [(block_height MOD 210000) + 1]

> What is the equation/algorithm used to determine this?

Value the of a Bitcoin block defined [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.0/src/main.cpp#L1223). The default value is 50 * 100,000,000 Satoshis.

After every "**SubsidyHalvingInterval**" blocks, the reward of each block halved. The **SubsidyHalvingInterval** is defined [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.0/src/chainparams.cpp#L118)

```
CAmount GetBlockValue(int nHeight, const CAmount& nFees)
{
    CAmount nSubsidy = 50 * COIN;
    int halvings = nHeight / Params().SubsidyHalvingInterval();

    // Force block reward to zero when right shift is undefined.
    if (halvings >= 64)
        return nFees;

    // Subsidy is cut in half every 210,000 blocks which will occur approximately every 4 years.
    nSubsidy >>= halvings;

    return nSubsidy + nFees;
}
```

Comment: Actually the block reward is `50/(2**(630001 // 210000))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [BlockExplorer API](http://blockexplorer.com/q/totalbc) *totalbc* query: `http://blockexplorer.com/q/totalbc/####`, where `####` can be a past or future block number, and the return value is the total BTC in circulation. *[bcperblock](http://blockexplorer.com/q/bcperblock)* may also be helpful.

See [BlockExplorer.com/q/](http://blockexplorer.com/q/) for a full list of queries.